# No Intellisense in Razor views after installing MVC 4 - Tried various solutions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, intellisense

I recently installed MVC 4 on VS2010, but I seem to occasionally be losing my intellisense. I tried installing MVC 4 again the other day, but still no luck on getting it back. This is my current Web.config under my project:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" /> //I've also tried setting it to 1.0.0.0
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

This is my Web.config under my Views folder:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc,     Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

**Solutions tried:**

- Reinstalling MVC 4
- Changing `<add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />` to `<add
  key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0" />`
- Changing `<add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0" />` back to `<add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />`
- Re-launching new instances of VS after changing settings above

Comment: Did you try cleaning the project in VS?

Comment: Yeah, no luck. I've even gone as far as uninstalling MVC 3 and 4 and re-installing. Still in the process of getting them back on, but I'll report back.

Comment: Put your cursor on the @model (if it has the blue squiggly line indicating an error). If you've installed certain NuGet packages it will show the error - For example: ASP.NET runtime error: The pre-application start initialization method Start on type Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.PreApplicationStartCode threw an
exception with the following error message: The type initializer for DotNetOpenAuth.Reporting threw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Delete anything but the 11.0 folder and it should solve it.
%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\

Comment: This didn't help me.  I think VS 2012 lost Intellisense for Razor files after I updated DotNetOpenAuth.  I've tried everything I've found on StackOverflow to restore Intellisense to no avail.  This makes me a sad panda.  (ETA: Intellisense correctly handles CSHTML files in a new solution.  I don't see any difference in web.config or other settings, though.)